# Runge-Kutta methods: step size greater than 1

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

The local truncation error of Runge-Kutta 4 is $O(h^5)$, while those of RK1 is $O(h^2)$.

I wonder then what happened when the step-size of RK methods is greater than 1: will the accuracy be improved if we choose RK1 instead of RK4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $\epsilon = O(h^p)$ describes behavior of the error when $h$ *tends to zero*. You cannot compare $O(h^2)$ and $O(h^5)$ just simply by comparing $h^2$ and $h^5$, in fact they have different multipliers, 
$$
\epsilon_\text{Euler} \approx C_E h^2\\
\epsilon_\text{RK4} \approx C_{RK4} h^5
$$
where both $C_E$ and $C_{RK}$ *depend on the problem being solved*.

For example, when these methods are applied to a linear ODE
$$
u' = \lambda u\\
u(0) = 1
$$
the local truncation error is 
$$
\epsilon_n = u_n \left[e^{\lambda h} - r(\lambda h)\right],
$$
where $r(z)$ is so-called stability function of the method. For the explicit Euler the stability function is
$$
r_E(z) = 1 + z
$$
and for the RK4 it is 
$$
r_{RK4} = 1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^3}{6} + \frac{z^4}{24},
$$
so
$$
\epsilon_{E} = u_n \sum_{k = 2}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k h^k}{k!}\\
\epsilon_{RK4} = u_n \sum_{k = 5}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k h^k}{k!}.
$$
It can be seen that it is not $h$, but $\lambda h$ what the ocal truncation error depends on. For systems of ODE the role of $\lambda$ roughly play the eigenvalues of the jacobian matrix of the system.

Here are $\epsilon_{E}$(blue) and $\epsilon_{RK4}$(yellow) plotted against $z = \lambda h$. The errors are almost the same (and really big) for moderate values of $z \gtrsim 5$. Both error behave like $\epsilon \approx e^z$ for big $z$, so the relative error is about $1$.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. In my case, I have got v = dx/dt and I want to know x. v is a kind of a black box. How could I evaluate then $\lambda$ ? My question is actually in order to define a range of admissible $h$.

Comment: Is $v = v(x)$ or $v = v(t)$ or $v = v(x,t)$?
If $v = v(t)$ then reasonable $\lambda \sim \frac{d\log v}{dt} = \frac{|v'(t)|}{|v(t)|}$. If $v = v(x)$ then $\lambda \sim |v'(x)|$

Comment: Oh smart! Thanks

Comment: You can replace/bound $λ$ with a Lipschitz constant of the ODE function. The error constants however are polynomials in the higher derivatives, if they do not scale commensurate with the Lipschitz constant, that is, grow far faster, the system is called "stiff".